# Complement of a language definition

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, regular-languages, logic

Let $A=\{$ M is a TM, $s\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\exists x\in\Sigma^*$ s.t M rejects $x$ in at most $s$ steps $\}$.

I want to define its complement, so how do I negate "$\exists x\in\Sigma^*$ s.t M rejects $x$ in at most $s$ steps"?

Is it:

$\forall x \in \Sigma^*$ M accepts $x$ in at most $s$ steps?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No. It's possible that $M$ neither accepts nor rejects $x$. The complement is "$M$ does not reject $x$ within $s$ steps."

Comment: Oh right! Thank you! Why did you write "within $s$ steps" instead of "at most"?

Comment: It sounded better to my Canadian ear.

Comment: @rici Got it! ;) Thanks! :)

Comment: @rici And should I replaced $\exists$ with $\forall$ ?

Comment: Yes, you.must do that